# Which loss function to use for a convolution NN for noise removal of high resolution images

Tags: regression, convolutional-neural-network, loss-function, image, noise

My task is to remove small random spots from my 4 mega pixel images.

My strategy was to feed a convolution network these images as I have the true images without the spots in them.

The current loss function that I have been using is mean absolute error. However, even after running thousands of iterations on just the one image it cannot produce the true image data. It gets very close but it has not been able to remove all of the intensity of a spot and a residual/lower intensity spot (intensity of 5-10 on an 8 bit scale) is still seen on the output image.

I am wondering if this is due to the size of the image being 4 million pixels and that the total number of pixels which contain spots would only be in there hundreds. My original images are only 8 bit images (0-255) but I first convert this to a float with range 0-1. So my thought is that the total loss is mostly made up of pixels that have less than a 1/255 error as these are in there millions but does not try and reduce the noisy spots that are in their hundreds but have an error or (5/255 to 10/255).

Is there another loss function that can bring more attention to the spot errors?

Is there a best practice for weighting these points of interest?

Is it ill advised to create a loss function that only worries about errors greater than 1/255, in terms of stability of the optimization?

Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

Denoising with classic CNN has its own limitations because they haven't been created for this purpose.

That's why you may have to improve the convolution/deconvolution process or apply other solutions so that you can remove noise or random spots more efficiently.

Here are available libraries that could do the job very well:

https://github.com/LabForComputationalVision/bias_free_denoising/blob/master/generalization_demo.ipynb

https://github.com/JWSoh/DUBD

https://github.com/chintan1995/Image-Denoising-using-Deep-Learning

Comment: Does it answer your question? If not, please let me know.